Cannot add vector search to an Azure AI Search data source
I have two instances of Azure Open AI Studio. Each has a Chat. I created an instance of Azure AI Search and added a vector index to it.
Now I am adding data to my Chats. I select Azure AI Search as data source. I select the available Azure AI Search service and the corresponding index is populated automatically.
There is an "Add vector search to this search resource" check box.
In one of the instances of Azure Open AI Studio this box is active and can be checked. In the other instance it is dimmed and cannot be checked. 
What I am doing wrong?
Thank you

"I created an instance of Azure AI Search and added a vector index to it." - please share how you did this. Alternatively, try Select data source as "Upload files" and create the index dynamically.

@David Makovoz is my solution helpful?

To enable that there are 2 conditions you should meet.

You need to have a vector column in your index
Existing embedding model in your azure openai resource.

Since, you already having vector column you no need to configure.

In one of the instances of Azure Open AI Studio this box is active and can be checked. In the other instance it is dimmed and cannot be checked.

This is because the one you can be able to check the vector search is having the embedding model in that instance.
So, create an embedding model in the Azure Open AI Studio where the check box is greyed and try to integrate with chat.
First, go to deployment and click on Create new deployment.

Next, select any one of the available model and click on create.

Know try integrating the ai search into azure openai.

I do have text-embedding-3-large deployed

I made a quick test on one of my resources and the selector only show text-embedding-ada-002 deployed model, even if I have a text-embedding-3-large available in addition. So it looks like a limitation from the portal @DavidMakovoz

Yes. as of know you can use text-embedding-ada-002 which is having 1536 min and max dimension.

@NaveenSharma I requested quota for text-embedding-ada-002, waiting. Can't verify until it gets approved.
